# Error in python script running in xampp windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, cgi

I am new to PYTHON and usually code on PHP. This is the first script I am trying to run on Windows XAMPP. I enabled addhandler for .py and trying to run the following script:

```
#!C:\Python33\python.exe
# enable debugging
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
print ("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8")
print ("Hello World!")
```

and I am getting the following error while running the code:

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.

Error message: 
malformed header from script 'test.py': Bad header: Hello World!

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Comment: Try not to re-invent the wheel - I suggest you use a framework instead of doing things by hand. [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org) is a great lightweight framework to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should separate headers from body printing additional newline:

```
#!C:\Python33\python.exe
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
print("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8")
print() # <----------- addtional newlnie for header/body separation.
print("Hello World!")
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who's still getting an error, try replacing print() by print("\r\n") in the following way:

```
print("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8")
print("\r\n")
print("Hello World!")
```

This should work!